# how to create edges for nodes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

In need a find the degree of every protein in the input file which is as shown below

```
A   B
a   b
c   d
a   c
c   b
```

I have used networkx to get the nodes. How do I create the edges using my input file on the created nodes?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('protein.txt',sep='\t', index_col =0)
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['a', 'b']

distinct = pd.concat([df['a'], df['b']]).unique()

import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()

nodes= []
for i in distinct:
    node=G.add_node(1)
    nodes.append(node)
```

Answer (score 0):

From `networkx` [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edge.html), use `add_edge` in the loop or collect edges first then use `add_edges_from`:

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()   # or DiGraph, MultiGraph, MultiDiGraph, etc
>>> e = (1,2)
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2)           # explicit two-node form
>>> G.add_edge(*e)             # single edge as tuple of two nodes
>>> G.add_edges_from( [(1,2)] ) # add edges from iterable container
```

Then `G.degree()` gives you the degree of nodes.

Comment: Yes, I had referred the documentation but I did understand where does my input file come into picture and how edges are formed. 
I tried the process as you suggested and I got the output as: [(1, 1), (2, 1)]

Answer (score 0):

At first, the function `read_csv` was used incorrectly to read the input file. The columns are separated by spaces, not tab, thus `sep` should be `'\s+'` instead of `'\t'`. Also, there is no index column in the input file, thus the parameter `index_col` should not be set to `0`.

After having correctly read the input file into a `DataFrame`, we can convert it to a `networkx` graph using the function [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html).

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('protein.txt', sep='\s+')
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'A', 'B')
```