# Error in creating the edges python

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

This question in reference with question - [how to create edges for nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722640/how-to-create-edges-for-nodes/49722962#49722962)

I used the suggestions and wrote a code but I am getting n error - ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',sep='\s+')
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
df = df.dropna(axis=0)

#distinct values to create nodes
distinct = pd.concat([df['a'], df['b']]).unique()

G=nx.Graph()

for i in distinct:
   node=G.add_node(1)

for i in df.iterrows():
   A = df['a'][i]
   B = df['b'][i]
   G.add_edge(A,B)
```

I am getting the error in the loop for creating edges but I do not understand what is the error and how to solve it.

Comment: Can you copy & paste the entire error message?

Comment: `df.iterrows()` yield a row each time, not an index.

Comment: `File "<ipython-input-101-9da8a1cd8f0d>", line 2, in <module>
A = df.a[i]
File "C:\Users\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 642, in __getitem__
return self._get_with(key)
File "C:\Users\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 655, in _get_with
return self._get_values_tuple(key)
File "C:\Users\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 700, in _get_values_tuple
raise ValueError('Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex')
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex`

Comment: Can you click the edit button under your question and put the error message into the question?  It's very hard to make sense of the error in the comment.

Comment: In your loop `for i in df.iterrows():` I very much doubt that `i` is an index.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions! The problem was with using iterrows. I found the error. Thanks again!